# Perdendo a barra ("/")

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Segue código:

```
var token = "bHhETtde1UhKpwUVmTsNTpXZKyfZGK8/";
var token_string = Uri.EscapeDataString(token); //"bHhETtde1UhKpwUVmTsNTpXZKyfZGK8%2F"
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{URL}/api/getall/{token_string}");
```

**ApiController:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAll (string token) {}
```

No parâmetro `token`, recebe `bHhETtde1UhKpwUVmTsNTpXZKyfZGK8` e perdeu a barrinha.

Como faço para não perder a "`/`" ?

Aqui tenho alguns exemplo de token:

- pj/Wgche1UjjQG8i/MqaS5ZqGp3Ob1rn
- lk/lpohe1Ujjdftg+GuiS5ZqGp25b1rn

Eu uso `EscapeDataString` por causa do caractere `+`, `/`, entre outras.

Não permitir string especial.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Não seria o caso de você remover a barra do final e colocar ela manual `getall/{token_string}/` ?

Comment: O problema é que o token pode gerar várias barras.

Comment: Tente usar o `Regex.Escape(string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele perde a última barra porque ela é interpretada como parte da URL e não como valor do seu parâmetro.

Se o seu token pode apresentar caracteres especiais ele não pode ser incluído em uma url de rota dessa maneira (crua), porque vai "quebrar" a URL.

A primeira coisa que você pode fazer é usar o `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode();` ou `WebUtility.UrlEncode()` se estamos falando de `Asp.Net Core`.

E para garantir a integridade da url, ao invés de passar como um parâmetro rota, você pode usar como Query String

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{URL}/api/getall/?token={token_string});
```

Mas eu não recomendaria você transportar o token como QueryString ou parâmetro de rota, meu entendimento é que ele não deveria ser exposto assim tão abertamente. Eu utilizaria um atributo de header para isso.

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar assim:

```
var token = @"bHhETtde1UhKpwUVmTsNTpXZKyfZGK8/";
```